# Incrementing a number at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, string

I'd like some help in writing a JavaScript function that Would detect a hyphen and a number at the end of my string:

ie.

```
var x = "filenumber-2"
```

If there is a hyphen at the end of my string then take the number after the hyphen and increment it by 1.

ie.

```
var x = "filenumber-3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
x = x.replace(/-\d+$/, function(n){ return '-'+(1-n) });
```

This increments the number only if it's after an hyphen and at end of the string.

Comment: How does that "detect a hyphen and a number at the end of my string"?

Comment: Wow...one line of code. That that is some rocket science =|. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonKelly Is it clear how it works or do you need some explanation on a specific part ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go along these lines:

```
increaseNumberAtEndOfString = function (input) {
    try {
        var ar = input.split("-");
        if (ar.length > 1) {
            var myNumber = Number(ar[ar.length - 1]);
            myNumber++;
            ar[ar.length - 1] = myNumber;
        }
        return ar.join("-");
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error("Invalid string!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var reg = /-\d+$/
if(reg.test(x)){
    x = x.replace(/(\d+)$/,function(a){return +a+1})
}
```

Comment: It can be done more efficiently with only one regex, see my answer.

Comment: @dystroy, yes, i've seen, it was answer on a question in comment about "how detect"